# How to count TRUE values in a logical vector

Tags: r

In R, what is the most efficient/idiomatic way to count the number of `TRUE` values in a logical vector? I can think of two ways:

```
z <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1000, rep = TRUE)
sum(z)
# [1] 498

table(z)["TRUE"]
# TRUE 
#  498
```

Which do you prefer? Is there anything even better?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

The safest way is to use `sum` with `na.rm = TRUE`:

```
sum(z, na.rm = TRUE) # best way to count TRUE values
```

which gives 1.

There are some problems with other solutions when logical vector contains `NA` values.

See for example:

```
z <- c(TRUE, FALSE, NA)

sum(z) # gives you NA
table(z)["TRUE"] # gives you 1
length(z[z == TRUE]) # f3lix answer, gives you 2 (because NA indexing returns values)
```

Additionally `table` solution is less efficient (look at the code of `table` function).

Also, you should be careful with the "table" solution, in case there are no TRUE values in the logical vector. See for example:

```
z <- c(FALSE, FALSE)
table(z)["TRUE"] # gives you `NA`
```

or

```
z <- c(NA, FALSE)
table(z)["TRUE"] # gives you `NA`
```

Comment: `table(c(FALSE))["TRUE"]` gives NA, not 0.

Comment: @YossiFarjoun Yes, and it's in my answer. This are examples why it won't work. My sollution is `sum(z, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Hm... na.rm is not available in RStudio?! there is na.actuion,exclude, fail etc.... but no rm. Whats could be the reason for it?

Comment: @Harry if you have unrelated problem ask new question

Comment: @Harry Answer is still valid

Comment: Yeah in deed it is valid, i needed to do Session->restart R to get it working in RStudio. Hope this helps others too :D

Answer (score 94):

Another option which hasn't been mentioned is to use `which`:

```
length(which(z))
```

Just to actually provide some context on the "which is faster question", it's always easiest just to test yourself.  I made the vector much larger for comparison:

```
z <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),1000000,rep=TRUE)
system.time(sum(z))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    0.03
system.time(length(z[z==TRUE]))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.75    0.07    0.83 
system.time(length(which(z)))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.34    0.28    1.64 
system.time(table(z)["TRUE"])
   user  system elapsed 
  10.62    0.52   11.19
```

So clearly using `sum` is the best approach in this case.  You may also want to check for `NA` values as Marek suggested.

Just to add a note regarding NA values and the `which` function:

```
> which(c(T, F, NA, NULL, T, F))
[1] 1 4
> which(!c(T, F, NA, NULL, T, F))
[1] 2 5
```

Note that which only checks for logical `TRUE`, so it essentially ignores non-logical values.

Comment: BTW, there was a nice trick with timing in Dirk answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748590/revolution-for-r/1748932#1748932

Answer (score 14):

Another way is

```
> length(z[z==TRUE])
[1] 498
```

While `sum(z)`  is nice and short, for me `length(z[z==TRUE])` is more self explaining. Though, I think with a simple task like this it does not really make a difference...

If it is a large vector, you probably should go with the fastest solution, which is `sum(z)`. `length(z[z==TRUE])` is about 10x slower and `table(z)[TRUE]` is about 200x slower than `sum(z)`.

Summing up, `sum(z)` is the fastest to type and to execute.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use summary function. It gives a summary of the Ts, Fs and NAs.

```
> summary(hival)
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical    4367      53    2076 
>
```

Comment: Further, to get only the "TRUE" results (which will be output as a string, but also includes "TRUE" in output): `summary(hival)["TRUE"]` ;

Answer (score 6):

`which` is good alternative, especially when you operate on matrices (check `?which` and notice the `arr.ind` argument). But I suggest that you stick with `sum`, because of `na.rm` argument that can handle `NA`'s in logical vector.
For instance:

```
# create dummy variable
set.seed(100)
x <- round(runif(100, 0, 1))
x <- x == 1
# create NA's
x[seq(1, length(x), 7)] <- NA
```

If you type in `sum(x)` you'll get `NA` as a result, but if you pass `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum` function, you'll get the result that you want.

```
> sum(x)
[1] NA
> sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 43
```

Is your question strictly theoretical, or you have some practical problem concerning logical vectors?

Comment: I was trying to grade a quiz. Doing something like sum(youranswer==rightanswer) within an apply.

Comment: My reply is just too long, so I posted a new answer, since it differs from previous one.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a package called `bit` that is specifically designed for fast boolean operations. It's especially useful if you have large vectors or need to do many boolean operations.

```
z <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1e8, rep = TRUE)

system.time({
  sum(z) # 0.170s
})

system.time({
  bit::sum.bit(z) # 0.021s, ~10x improvement in speed
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing something similar a few weeks ago. Here's a possible solution, it's written from scratch, so it's kind of beta-release or something like that. I'll try to improve it by removing loops from code...

The main idea is to write a function that will take 2 (or 3) arguments. First one is a `data.frame` which holds the data gathered from questionnaire, and the second one is a numeric vector with correct answers (this is only applicable for single choice questionnaire). Alternatively, you can add third argument that will return numeric vector with final score, or data.frame with embedded score.

```
fscore <- function(x, sol, output = 'numeric') {
    if (ncol(x) != length(sol)) {
        stop('Number of items differs from length of correct answers!')
    } else {
        inc <- matrix(ncol=ncol(x), nrow=nrow(x))
        for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
            inc[,i] <- x[,i] == sol[i]
        }
        if (output == 'numeric') {
            res <- rowSums(inc)
        } else if (output == 'data.frame') {
            res <- data.frame(x, result = rowSums(inc))
        } else {
            stop('Type not supported!')
        }
    }
    return(res)
}
```

I'll try to do this in a more elegant manner with some *ply function. Notice that I didn't put `na.rm` argument... Will do that

```
# create dummy data frame - values from 1 to 5
set.seed(100)
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(round(runif(200,1,5)), 10))
# create solution vector
sol <- round(runif(20, 1, 5))
```

Now apply a function:

```
> fscore(d, sol)
 [1] 6 4 2 4 4 3 3 6 2 6
```

If you pass data.frame argument, it will return modified data.frame.
I'll try to fix this one... Hope it helps!

Comment: One-liner: `rowSums(t(t(d)==sol), na.rm=TRUE)`. R recycle vector for comparison. If your `d` were matrix with cases in columns then its simplifies to `rowSums(d==sol, na.rm=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a particular problem where I had to count the number of true statements from a logical vector and this worked best for me...

```
length(grep(TRUE, (gene.rep.matrix[i,1:6] > 1))) > 5
```

So This takes a subset of the gene.rep.matrix object, and applies a logical test, returning a logical vector. This vector is put as an argument to grep, which returns the locations of any TRUE entries. Length then calculates how many entries grep finds, thus giving the number of TRUE entries.