# How to count number of TRUE values in a logical vector before FALSE

Tags: r, logical-operators

While trying to find number of `TRUE` values in a vector, I came across the first   [Google hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190756/how-to-count-true-values-in-a-logical-vector). However, this does not fully meet my requirements. I am interested to find the number of `TRUE` values in a vector before the first `FALSE` if any.  I have a vector `a <- c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE, TRUE)` and want to find all `TRUE` values before the `FALSE`, so output will be three. Kindly note that it should also work if there are only `TRUE` values in the vector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a short way:

```
sum(cumprod(a))
# [1] 3
```

where `cumprod` gives a cumulative product (of zeros and ones in this case); so, it eliminates all `TRUE`'s after the first `FALSE`, as in

```
cumprod(a)
# [1] 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the below statement we can get the result easily.

```
which.min(a)-1
```

Comment: ...somewhat faster on large vectors than the solution based on `cumprod()`. For a deliberatly bad example compare the two solutions on: `a <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), c(42, 1, 1e8))`.

Comment: This method will not work for a vector containing only `TRUE` values. Working only for a combination of `TRUE,FALSE`

Comment: OK, then you need another `if()` check afterwards. If the result is `0` you need to change it to `length(a)`. If you need to apply this very many times or on very large data, the timing will still be better. If you just need this as a convenience function then the one-line solution based on `cumprod()` might be quicker to type/remember.

Comment: Not always!! That will work only with all `TRUE` values, if all are `FALSE` , in that case also `0` is returned , and can not change it to length(a)