# How to count number of TRUEs in a row?

Tags: r

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190756/how-to-count-true-values-in-a-logical-vector), but it is not working in my case.

I have a dataset like below:

```
dt<-data.frame(A=c(F,F,F),B=(T,F,T),C=(T,T,F))
```

I want to add a forth column which shows number of T. So, in my case it would be

```
count
2
1
1
```

I have tired this solution with

```
sum( as.vector(dt[1,]))
```

but it complains with

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

I am sure, i have no `NA`

Comment: Just use `rowSums(dt)`

Comment: You shouldn't use T and F for TRUE and FALSE in R as they're not protected keywords.