# How to check if a value is present in an interval

Tags: r

I'd like to check if some values I have generated are present in a certain interval (-2.20:2.20 in this case). I thought of creating a vector from -2.20 to 2.20 but didn't figure out how to do so as well.

Comment: How about `x > -2.2 & x < 2.2`, calling your input `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using logical operators.

```
x >= int[1] & x <= int[2]
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or `%between%` in package `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
x %between% int
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(10, 0, 3) 
int <- c(-2.20, 2.20)
```

Comment: That works fine I guess, thank you! Also, I wanted to count the FALSE values and for that I found some useful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190756/how-to-count-true-values-in-a-logical-vector

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `between` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
x <- 1:3
between(x, -2.2,2.2)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would have to look something like this:

> attach(df)
>
> exists("varName")
> [1] TRUE

Comment: How does this check if values are between -2.2 and 2.2?